# ¿ Como eliminar las imagenes de Storage de Firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, delete, firebase-storage

Estoy tratando de adaptar un proyecto React Native a los nuevos metodos de Firebase.
En el subo imágenes al `Storage` y se añaden a la interfaz de la App.
Tambien puedo eliminar estas imagenes de la interfaz como muestro en el siguiente código:

```
const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result)
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    ) 
  }
```

El problema esta en que de este modo, solo se eliminan de mi App, mientras que las imagenes siguen almacenadas en `Firebase`.
Mi idea es que , cuando elimino las imagenes de la interfaz, tambien se eliminen de el `Storage de Firebase`.

[He leido documentación de `Firebase`,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/delete-files) y con la `[función deleteObject][1]`, se puede conseguir lo que busco, pero he probado diferentes formas, y no consigo que funcione.
¿ Pueden ayudarme a implementar esta función en mi código ?

```
import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject,  uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"


export function UploadImagesForm(props) {
  const { formik } = props
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false) // status for loading

// Función encargada de abrir la galería de imágenes
  const openGallery = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      // console.log('buscando imagenes')
      setIsLoading(true) // uploading the image
      uploadImage(result.uri)
    }
  }

// funcion para subir las imagenes a Firebase
  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()

    const storage = getStorage()
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `restaurants/${uuid()}`)

  // vamos al almacenamiento donde queremos guardar las imágenes
    uploadBytes(storageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot)
      updatePhotosRestaurant(snapshot.metadata.fullPath)
    })
  }

 // tomamos la URL en la función anterior y la ponemos en el estado del formulario
  const updatePhotosRestaurant = async (imagePath) => {
    const storage = getStorage()
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)


    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef) // get the url

    // código para cargar todas las imágenes sin reemplazarlas
     // obtener las imágenes actuales y agregar las nuevas con la matriz

    formik.setFieldValue("images", [...formik.values.images, imageUrl])

    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result)
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    ) 
  }

  return (

    <>
      <ScrollView
        style={Styles.viewImage}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <Icon
          type="material-community"
          name="camera"
          color="#a7a7a7"
          containerStyle={Styles.containerIcon}
          onPress={openGallery}
        />
        {map(formik.values.images, (image) => ( // display the images on the screen
          <Avatar
            key={image}
            source={{ uri: image }}
            containerStyle={Styles.imageStyle}
            onPress={() => removeImage(image)}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <Text style={Styles.error}>{formik.errors.images}</Text>
      <LoadingModal show={isLoading} text="Subiendo la imagen" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: primero tenes que conseguir el REF, lo instancias y le das .delete() y se borra del storage, nisiquiera hace falta que hagas el filtro. Te dejo la documentacion.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/delete-files

Comment: ¿ Y como implemento esto en React Native ? No se como hacerlo con la documentación de React Native, menos aún con la de Flutter. Gracias @ErickSilva

Comment: @MiguelEspeso y podrias mostrar de que forma estas intentando implementar lo que intentaste y no funciona? despues de la linea ``formik.setFieldValue("images", result)``, en la funcion de eliminar imagen, lo primero que deberias hacer segun la documentacion es obtener la ref a la imagen. Podes obtenerla? Que pasa si le haces un console log a esta ref?

Comment: ¿ Y donde añado `ref` ? Como veras. ya esta `const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)` Añadi console.log(ref) debajo de  la linea formik.setFieldValue("images", result) y recibo lo siguiente: `[Function ref]`

Comment: @MiguelEspeso el console que debes hacer seria ``console.log(imageRef)``, ya que ref es una funcion.

Comment: si imageRef devuelve algo diferente a ``undefined`` o ``null`` deberias tener la referencia. Ahi deberias poder eliminarla. Podrias probar haciendo la funcion asincrona ``const removeImage = async (img) => { `` y luego, donde estas haciendo el console, pone ``await deleteObject(imageRef)``

Comment: @MiguelEspeso por otro lado ``const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)`` no esta dentro de tu funcion eliminar, no te va a andar lo que te digo, la referencia la necesitas dentro de la funcion eliminar. Deberias volver a declarar ahi adentro ``const imageRef = ref(storage, img)``, es decir, deberias armar la referencia a partir de la imagen que recibis como parametro. No se si deberias mandarle ``img`` especificamente. Para eso deberiamos consolear ``img`` a ver que tiene

Comment: **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: imageRef**. esto recibo con `formik.setFieldValue("images", result)
            console.log(imageRef)`

Comment: Hasta ahora del modo que esta, eliminaba la imagen de la aplicación pero no de Firebase, hice los cambios que me sugieres y dentro de la función tambien recibo errores ¿ Puedes mostrarme un ejemplo practico para hacer mejor las pruebas ? Estoy revolviendo todo el código y no se como terminara esto jjjjjj

Comment: @MiguelEspeso te voy a subir en una respuesta lo que trato de ayudarte pero no la tomes como algo valido, no se de react native, solo react

Comment: Bueno, por lo menos estas tratando de ayudar, muestra y lo coloco en la App. Total, React Native

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137628/discussion-between-agustin-g-and-miguel-espeso).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero redeclaramos `storage` porque lo vamos a usar en 3 lugares distintos, para no crearlo cada vez. Tambien lo quito de los lugares donde lo declarabas.

Luego hice las modificaciones pertinentes en la funcion `removeImage`, agregando el siguiente bloque:

```
        const imageRef = ref(storage, img); // creamos la referencia a la imagen
         // eliminamos, tal cual nos muestra la documentacion
         deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => {
           console.log("la imagen se elimino");
         }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("ocurrio un error: ", error);
         });
```

Tu componente finalmente quedaria asi:

```
import { getStorage, ref, deleteObject,  uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"


export function UploadImagesForm(props) {
  const { formik } = props
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false) // status for loading
  const storage = getStorage(); // La declaro afuera de las funciones, sino la tenes que declarar en cada una de ellas. Elimine las declaraciones.

// Función encargada de abrir la galería de imágenes
  const openGallery = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    })

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      // console.log('buscando imagenes')
      setIsLoading(true) // uploading the image
      uploadImage(result.uri)
    }
  }

// funcion para subir las imagenes a Firebase
  const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri)
    const blob = await response.blob()

    const storageRef = ref(storage, `restaurants/${uuid()}`)

  // vamos al almacenamiento donde queremos guardar las imágenes
    uploadBytes(storageRef, blob).then((snapshot) => {
      // console.log(snapshot)
      updatePhotosRestaurant(snapshot.metadata.fullPath)
    })
  }

 // tomamos la URL en la función anterior y la ponemos en el estado del formulario
  const updatePhotosRestaurant = async (imagePath) => {
    const imageRef = ref(storage, imagePath)

    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef) // get the url

    // código para cargar todas las imágenes sin reemplazarlas
     // obtener las imágenes actuales y agregar las nuevas con la matriz

    formik.setFieldValue("images", [...formik.values.images, imageUrl])

    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  const removeImage = (img) => { // delete an image selected by the user
    Alert.alert(
      "Eliminar imagen",
      "¿Estás seguro de eliminar esta imagen?",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancelar",
          style: "cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Eliminar",
          onPress: () => {
            const result = filter(
              formik.values.images,
              (image) => image !== img
            )
            formik.setFieldValue("images", result);
            const imageRef = ref(storage, img); 
             deleteObject(imageRef).then(() => {
               console.log("la imagen se elimino");
             }).catch((error) => {
                console.log("ocurrio un error: ", error);
             });
          },
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    ) 
  }

  return (

    <>
      <ScrollView
        style={Styles.viewImage}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <Icon
          type="material-community"
          name="camera"
          color="#a7a7a7"
          containerStyle={Styles.containerIcon}
          onPress={openGallery}
        />
        {map(formik.values.images, (image) => ( // display the images on the screen
          <Avatar
            key={image}
            source={{ uri: image }}
            containerStyle={Styles.imageStyle}
            onPress={() => removeImage(image)}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <Text style={Styles.error}>{formik.errors.images}</Text>
      <LoadingModal show={isLoading} text="Subiendo la imagen" />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: El problema esta en await que devuelve error de sintaxis

Comment: @MiguelEspeso agregaste async a la delcaracion de la funcion?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso perdon, el async va en la funcion ``onPress``, edité el codigo. Fijate en los comentarios de tu pregunta, tenes un link a un chat.